# how can I get closest `selectbox` in a table ? `jquery` or `js`

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a table like this:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <select name="state" class="state-elem" onchange="shop_address_update(this)"></select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="city" class="city-elem" onchange="shop_address_update(this)"></select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="main_street" class="main-street-elem" onchange="shop_address_update(this)"></select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to fill city selectbox after choosing an state, question is how can I find the `$(".city-elem")` to fill it with my values.

I tried `$(this).closest('.city-elem')` but when I `console.log` the result is: `r.fn.init(0)` and I can not fill it.

how can I found that selectbox?

Comment: `closest` checks the element itself, and then traverses upwards in the DOM. Your state select field does not itself have the class `city-elem` - nor does it have any _ancestor_ with that class.

Comment: You should use `.parents()` to go up to the `tr` element, and then `.find()` what you are looking for in there.

Comment: `closest` = `nearest parent` - not nearest in the source code

Comment: `r.fn.init(0)` means you've logged a jquery object - use `console.log(jqueryobject.length)` to see if there's any matches.

Comment: As above: `$(this).closest("tr").find(".city-elem")`